# Unable to extra audio from Video file - Error Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: audio, video, extract

I am using the following command to try to extract audio from a very high end video file test case. I am getting the following error after using the command:

```
ffmpeg -i Chess.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame chess.mp3
```

```
ffmpeg version N-93322-gd227ed5d59 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.103 / 58. 47.103
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[mpegts @ 0000027df4e297c0] start time for stream 1 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0000027df4e297c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'Chess.mp4':
  Duration: 00:01:52.98, start: 1.066722, bitrate: 62538 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x101]: Video: hevc (Main 10) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x102](und): Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels
Output #0, mp3, to 'chess.mp3':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Comment: Are you sure your video is actually MPEG-4 file `.mp4`? Can it play in VLC media player?

Comment: yes It can play at vlc but its taking a couple of minutes to load.